# IOS 14 Images not showing in react native

Tags: ios, image, react-native, react-native-ios, ios14

> I am unable to render Images on IOS 14 Simulator and Iphone
>
> using Image from react-native and react-native-fast-image

Answer (score 1):

**It can display the image after adding [super displayLayer:layer]; if _currentFrame is nil if I understand correctly, _currentFrame should be for animated image, so if it is still image, we can use the UIImage implementation to handle image rendering, not sure if it is a correct fix.**

> react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m

```
 if (_currentFrame) {
    layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
    layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
  } else {
    [super displayLayer:layer];
  }
```